# No matching version found for @babel/traverse@^7.14.0

Tags: reactjs, npm

I tried to clone a project and run `npm install` and came across this error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @babel/traverse@^7.14.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@babel/helper-module-transforms'
npm ERR! notarget
```

I already googled and found some answers myself where a user was having problems with babel modules and the owner redirected it to here: https://gist.github.com/hzoo/df94af2d2ec48696e683b772c775aa67

We use a proxy for our company npm package, although I removed it from package.json for testing whether the issue was due to that, but still got the same problem.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

but no luck

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.6",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app-tsc": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-facebook": "^8.1.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-twitter-embed": "^3.0.3",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.4",
    "sp-rest-proxy": "^3.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "server": "node server.js",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react-app": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Running the `npm show @babel/traverse time`  command shows version `7.14.0` was published to the npm registry only yesterday _(at `2021-04-29T20:10:12.561Z` to be precise)_. When did you try running `npm install` - was it a few minutes ago, or yesterday?

Comment: a few minutes ago, I already checked npm package, just cloned the package today after npm release and ran npm install now an got the same error, I never ran npm install this project before

edit: I ran npm show and latest is 7.13.17 what should I do? Also tried yarn install it offers me available packges but not the new one

Comment: Very strange. Running the `npm show @babel/traverse version` command reports `7.14.0` as the latest version. It seems similar to [issue #3111](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3111)

Comment: I can't understand why my powershell shows the newest one while in the project show old one

Comment: allright I resolved the issue, I will write it down in a minute @RobC thanks for your effort, you were my rubberduck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because that version was published yesterday on the NPM registry but your company's registry is not up to date.

**SOLUTION**: open '.npmrc' which is located in your root. Comment out your first registry like this:

```
# registry=http://*******/*******/*****/
```

and add this:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Install that package version you need and then change back these 'registry' lines.

Comment: I did that, but this is so much pain :D wish there was an another way

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for those of us that use company registries.

Comment: I would just like to add that if it doesn't get added to the registry, this may break your build as your CI/CD will encounter the same issue

Answer (score 8):

after npm cache clean --force .works fine!

Comment: It was about company registry, the solution is above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It works, user behind corporate proxy

Answer (score 3):

I ran npm doctor to see what is wrong and realized that I couldn't remove my registry so doctor said I should have set the registry to https://registry.npmjs.org/, though I had .npmrc file and it replenished. After deleting that installation continued although package that came from our company couldn't, that is an another issue to solve

Answer (score 2):

set this npm config set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
and install npm

Answer (score 0):

You are running an outdated version of npm that doesn't recognise that version of @babel.

Run `npm update` then try cloning the project again, it should work.

Comment: It is something different, please check my answer above

Answer (score 0):

1. create a .npmrc file in the node folder, if it does not exist, or if it does, open it and сomment out ur first registry like this:

## registry=http://*******/*******/*****/

and add  registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/

2. npm install
3. npm cache clean --force

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).