# create-react-app: No matching version found for @babel/types@^7.22.18

Tags: npm, babeljs, create-react-app, aws-amplify

I try to run [this `create-react-app` command](https://create-react-app.dev/), according to [the AWS amplify tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/react/#initialize-a-new-backend)

```
npx create-react-app react-amplified
```

Eventually I get this error:

```
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @babel/types@^7.22.18.
```

Note I am running this as an admin on my personal laptop -- I don't think I use a proxy, I don't think I have a "company registry".

I checked these questions:

- [No matching version found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074762/no-matching-version-found)
- [Error while installing react in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446709/error-while-installing-react-in-visual-studio-code)
- [No matching version found for @babel/traverse@^7.14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67333444/no-matching-version-found-for-babel-traverse7-14-0)

I tried to clean my cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And I tried to update my registry:

```
npm config set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

But still I get the error.

Is this a case where the babel version 7.22.18, legitimately doesn't exist, according to the npmjs registry?

I am running this command at 9/14/2023 10:15AM MST (GMT-6) (aka 2023-09-14 4:15 UTC)...

Indeed I cannot see that npmjs has a 7.22.18 version, when I visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/types?activeTab=versions ...
the only thing I see is the 7.22.17 version:

[image: screenshot of https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/types?activeTab=versions showing only 7.22.17 version, no mention of 7.22.18]

I also don't see the 7.22.18 package available on the yarn registry:
[image: screenshot of https://yarnpkg.com/package?q=babel%2Ftypes&name=%40babel%2Ftypes showing only 7.22.17 version, no mention of 7.22.18]

It seems like the specific version `@babel/types@^7.22.18`; note [the caret `^` means...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/1175496)

> `^1.2.3` "Compatible with version" will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. ^1.2.3 will use releases from 1.2.3 to <2.0.0.

... so this means create-react-app is searching for babel version `@babel/types@^7.22.18` through  `<8.0.0`, right?

Note, **just a few minutes before** I ran the above command with a *failure*, I ran the above command *successfully*. The command created a directory and installed all the necessary packages, but I had a typo in my directory name, so I deleted it and tried again. I restored the deleted file to see that it used `@babel/core@7.22.17`, which has a dependency on `"@babel/types": "^7.22.17",` (see screenshot below). Therefore I hope [@Cosimo is correct and it's just a matter of waiting for the registry index to update...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77106836/1175496)

[image: when the npx create-react-app runs successfully, it uses @babel/core@7.22.17]

**UPDATE** *This is fixed now*...

Thanks to @Bomel for crosslinking ...

- this [the github issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15966) on the babel repository
- also see [this github issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15967)...
- and [this github issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/12394) in the nestjs repository...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here, but... it seems 7.22.18 was published just a few minutes ago: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/core/v/7.22.18

Perhaps it was a case of dependent packages being updated first.

As of 2023-09-14 16:32 UTC, @babel/types it's still at 7.22.17, but hopefully it will be updated **soon**...

UPDATE: and 7.22.19 is there now, 16:36 UTC.

UPDATE2: @Bomel mentioned the github issue https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15966

Comment: Nice observation, thanks! So do you think it's just a matter of **waiting some time**, then [`@babel/types/v/7.22.18` will be found](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/types/v/7.22.18)?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Still at 7.22.17 as of now, but I would hope .18 makes its way into the npm index soon. Meanwhile... all projects are not installable. Nice.

Comment: I think you must be right; I updated my question to show that a few minutes minutes before my failure, I had success, when `create-react-app` installed @babel/core/7.22.17 ... I see now @babel/core/7.22.18, and @babel/core/7.22.19 both exist, but still no @babel/**types**/7.22.18 ... Maybe the registry index updates the top-level packages (the "dependent packages" like @babel/core), first, like you said! Hopefully in a few minutes it will be fixed. Once the registry is updated, I think the problem will be fixed and I will mark your answer correct.

Comment: Now my command works (2023-09-14 16:40 UTC); I guess it's related to [this bug](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15966) (thanks @Bomel). @babel/core/7.22.19 , which in turn depends on "@babel/types": "^7.22.19", -- and now I [**can** reach "@babel/types": "^7.22.19"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/types/v/7.22.19)

Answer (score 3):

I think, there is a bug, and they are on it (see [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15966)).

Comment: Thank you for crosslinking; you're right, it seems to be fixed! I wish I could give you "Correct Answer" also...

Comment: @NateAnderson no worries, I'm happy, that they have fixed it so fast. Have a nice day :)